# Comparing classes of items to execute function(variable variable?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, comparison

In Jquery, I want to compare the classes of an h3 and a div. However, I have a lot of these and I can't go through and do case switches because more of these may be added in the future. Here is an example:

```
<h3 class="one">One</h3>
<h3 class="two">Two</h3>
<h3 class="three">Three</h3>
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
<div class="three">Three</div>
```

On clicking the h3, the div will toggle show/hide. However, as I said, there are a lot of these. Is there any way to say in Jquery that

```
if h3[class] = div[class] {
       //do something
}
```

without having to state each case of class comparison? Maybe a variable or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `h3` and `div` are DOM nodes and only have one class each

```
if (h3.className === div.className) {
    /* runs if both h3 and div have the same class attribute value.
}
```

For multiple classes I recommend you use ES5 and classlist

```
if (Array.prototype.every.call(h3.classList, function(v) {
        return div.classList.contains(v);
    })
) {
    /* runs if both h3 and div share the same classes */
}
```

[`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList), [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

Comment: Would I still have to define the class, in the first example? The whole point is I'm gonna have like 50 of these things and I want it to detect whether the classes are the same without actually having to state each class.

Comment: @user787885 no you don't. It checks whether they are the same by comparing the `className` or all the classes in the `classList`